# Using libraries in an android project

Tags: android, eclipse, cardslib

I have found a library that I'd like to use for my android app. On the github page of the project, there is a tutorial on how to add the library to your own app so that you can use it, but I have problems following it: https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/BUILD.md#reference-this-project-as-a-library-in-eclipse I know how to add .jars or projects as libraries to my own project using eclipse, but I don't get the library into my workspace in the first place.

Comment: The instructions are pretty neat and straight-forward. In which step are you stuck?

Comment: I'm already stuck on the second step. I try to add the folder to my work space as a project, but it won't show up as a project in the wizard.

Comment: I think that today the best way is gradle. 
About jars. In this case you can't use a jar because this library has some resources files (and jar can't contain them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, File -> import -> Android (NOT General) -> Existing Android Code into Workspace -> Select the library folder -> you should see the library

If the import option is not given, make sure you don't have any project by name "main" in your workspace. If you do, rename that project to something else and repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked that way. But I still don't have access to the functions of the added library. Is there anything that I still have to do before I can use the library features?

Comment: To your question, this IS THE answer. If you have a different issue, please post a new question.